# Easy tool for speeding up multiple sections of a Movie

Tags: video-editing

I have a movie file with a total length of 10min. All known movie editing suites are total overhead for me, like Premiere etc.

I want to speed up (playback speed) a lot of sections (like 20 sections) in this movie file by a specific speed, like 500% - leaving only some specific sections in original playback speed.

I'm imagining a convenient to use Windows tool where I just play the movie and click a button or shortcut to set points (alternate between in/out points) or something like that without all the hassle of editing/cutting on a video editing timeline with all the specialized functions.

Any ideas? Thanks so much!